# Array and object iteration in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, javascript-objects, for-of-loop

This is my code:

```js
// Task 1
var dairy = ['cheese', 'sour cream', 'milk', 'yogurt', 'ice cream', 'milkshake']
const logDairy = () => {
  for (const item of dairy) {
    console.log(item);
  }
}
logDairy();

const animal = {
  canJump: true
};
const bird = Object.create(animal);
bird.canFly = true;
bird.hasFeathers = true;

// Task 2
const birdCan = () => {
  for (const key of bird) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${Objects.value[item]}`);
  }
}
birdCan();

// Task 3
const animalCan = () => {
  for (const key in animal) {
    console.log(key);
  }
}
animalCan();
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: bird is not iterable

I am trying to get this output:

The expected output should be:

```
cheese
sour cream
milk
yogurt
ice cream
milkshake

canFly: true
hasFeathers: true

canFly: true
hasFeathers: true
canJump: true
```

Comment: What is `Objects.value`?

Comment: Why use `for..in` for `animal`, but `for..of` for `bird`?

Comment: My bad, its Object.values is a built-in method.

Comment: You may use for (const key in bird) , and then use `${key}: ${bird[key]}`

Comment: This is programming assignment, so i have to do in this way.

Comment: for in loop, loops over property as well as prototype.

Comment: for of loop, loops just over the property.

Comment: "*for of loop, loops just over the property.*" no, `for..of` loops go through iterable elements like arrays. Plain objects are not iterable.